# Assign matching values from small df to large df

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 data frames of unequal size and I want to map values from the smaller data frame to the larger one based on the "color" column.

df1:

| Color | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Red | A |
| Blue | B |
| Green | C |

df2:

| Color | Repetition |
| --- | --- |
| Red | 1 |
| Green | 1 |
| Red | 2 |
| Blue | 1 |
| Blue | 2 |
| ... | ... |

Desired output:

| Color | Repetition | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 1 | A |
| Green | 1 | C |
| Red | 2 | A |
| Blue | 1 | B |
| Blue | 2 | B |
| ... | ... | ... |

Reproducible code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(c("Red", "Blue", "Green"),
                  c("A", "B", "C"))
names(df1) <- c("Color", "Value")

df2 <- data.frame(c("Red", "Green", "Red", "Blue", "Blue"),
                  c(1,1,2,1,2))
names(df2) <- c("Color", "Repetition")
```

I've tried merge but it didn't work for me probably because they are of different sizes. I've also tried googling for this problem  but have only found python solutions.

Comment: Thats funny. Im trying to do this with Python and none of the solutions I am finding are working.

Answer (score 0):

Another satisfactory answer could be found here.

```
merge(df2, df1, by = "Color", all.x=TRUE)

 Color Repetition Value
1  Blue          1     B
2  Blue          2     B
3 Green          1     C
4   Red          1     A
5   Red          2     A
```